# JS issue in IE, with dissapearing text in input field on onfocus

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this code from here: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9BpGC/

But as an external JS file.

I have:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" placeholder="First text input box." onfocus="clearText()"  />
```

External JS:

```
function clearText() 
{
    $('input:text').each(
        function(){
            $(this)
                .val($(this).attr('placeholder'))
                .css('color','#999');
            $(this).click(
                function(){
                    $(this)
                        .val('')
                        .css('color','#000');
                });
            $(this).blur(
                function(){
                    if ($(this).val() === ''){
                        $(this)
                            .val($(this).attr('placeholder'))
                            .css('color','#999');
                    }
                });
        }
    );
}
```

It works in FF5, Chrome but not in IE8 unless I click in the box to load the search hint - if you use the demo on jsFiddle, it works fine across the different browsers, so is there a way to fix it to work with an external JS?

Comment: Maybe it's how you call that external .js file... how you do it ? Do you set the type="text/javascript" when you call it ?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/formText.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

My guess: it doesn't have to do with the externality of the file, but your implementation.

Rather than putting this logic inside of a function (`clearText()`) in this case, you should really put it in `$(document).ready`; this logic only needs to happen once, and it should happen when the document is ready (this is how [the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9BpGC/) does it). Your code should look something more like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Placeholder text logic
    $('input:text').each(function() {
        // the code you already have
    });

});
```

That is the only apparent difference between what you're doing and what that example does.